# Jsoup to POST login

Tags: javascript, android, http-headers, jsoup

Excuse my English, I'm learning. I am trying to login via Jsoup. However, there is a javascript function in the form to be sent via post. It will be if there is any way to execute the Encriptar_Enviar() function in Jsoup.

```
 <form name="frmLogin" action="javascript:Encriptar_Enviar();void(0);"><table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
              <tbody><tr>
                   <td colspan="3" class="txt">

                   </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td class="subsubtitulo">Login</td>
                   <td class="subsubtitulo">Senha</td>
                   <td width="24%" rowspan="3" id="td_btn_ok"><input id="btnOk" class="btnOk" type="submit" name="Submit" value="OK">
                   </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td width="36%" class="conteudoTexto">
                        <input class="formulario" name="LOGIN" type="text" id="txtLogin" size="15" maxlength="30">
                   </td>
                   <td width="40%" valign="top">
                        <input class="formulario" name="SENHA" type="password" id="txtSenha" size="15" maxlength="30">
                   </td>
              </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">

                    <a href="https://qacademico.ifpe.edu.br/qacademicodotnet/recuperar_senha.aspx">Esqueci minha senha</a>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <script src="lib/scripts/logins.js"></script>
    </tbody></table><input type="hidden" name="TIPO_USU" value="1"></form>
```

Here is my code, but it is giving error. Please help me.

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://qacademico.ifpe.edu.br/qacademico/index.asp?t=1001")
         .method(Connection.Method.GET)
         .execute();

    Map<String, String> loginCookies = loginForm.cookies();

    Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("https://qacademico.ifpe.edu.br/qacademico/lib/validalogin.asp")
        .data("Submit", "OK")
        .data("LOGIN", "MATRICULA_DO_ALUNO")
        .data("SENHA", "SENHA_DO_ALUNO")
        .data("TIPO_USU", "1")
        .cookies(loginCookies)
        .post();
```

Comment: *"but it is giving error."* What error are you getting?

Comment: This code is not entering the page. You're accusing the login is wrong. Possibly I'm missing the POST

Comment: I can assure you I am not assuming anything. I am simply asking if you have checked or see any errors in the console....

Answer (score 0):

This one is very tricky and it's impossible to do it using Jsoup. It doesn't just post your login and password when you submit the form. It GETs this additional URL: https://qacademico.ifpe.edu.br/qacademico/lib/rsa/gerador_chaves_rsa.asp?form=frmLogin&action=%2Fqacademico%2Flib%2Fvalidalogin%2Easp to obtain RSA keypair.
[image: generate keys]

Then it encrypts your data using this javascript library: https://qacademico.ifpe.edu.br/qacademico/lib/rsa/RSA.js and posts your login data encrypted:
[image: postencoded]